# Copy an Excel sheet and move to a new location using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I am new to SSIS, and want to check if it is possible to copy Excel Sheet and paste it in a new location.

For eg: I have an Excel named **Source.xlsx** which has 3 sheets ( Sheet A, Sheet B & Sheet C).
I just want to copy whole **Sheet B** (I **don't** need Sheet A & Sheet C) to another location, with a new **Customized File Name**.

And I have to do this for multiple Excel sheets. Like I have a **Source Folder** with 10 such Excel Files, I want to move the **Sheet B** from all those files to a **new Destination folder** as **10 separate Excel files** with **Customized names**.

I hope my question was clear.

Thanks & Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

1. Define a Foreach container and loop through excel files
2. Define a Dataflow task under Foreach container, to load sheet from the excel file to excel destination.
3. Define a variable `SheetName`, which holds the sheet name and use that variable as the source in the Excel Source. [Reference article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

[image: Excel Source][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7H3b.png)

4. Now, load this data to Excel Destination. Leverage the variable created in step no. 3 and use it as the destination. Have file name as Expression. [Read more on Excel destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/excel-destination?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You might need a $ on the sheet name.

Comment: Variable content will have $. Variable is just defined at SSIS level.